# Blender spacebar search additions

Tags: python, scripting

I would like to add spacebar search items and have resulting reminders displayed.  These reminders would be common keystrokes or combinations and wouldn't result in any operations.  Or, maybe they would...  Is there any way to edit search fields and results?